# Repeat the rows in a data frame based on values in a specific column

Tags: r, repeat

I would like to repeat entire rows in a data-frame based on the `samples` column.

My input:

```
df <- 'chr start end samples
        1   10   20    2
        2   4    10    3'
df <- read.table(text=df, header=TRUE)
```

My expected output:

```
df <- 'chr start end  samples
        1   10   20   1-10-20-s1
        1   10   20   1-10-20-s2
        2   4    10   2-4-10-s1
        2   4    10   2-4-10-s2
        2   4    10   2-4-10-s3'
```

Some idea how to perform it wisely?

Comment: you can use `df[rep(seq(nrow(df)), df$samples),]`

Answer (score 8):

We can use `expandRows` to expand the rows based on the value in the 'samples' column, then convert to `data.table`, grouped by 'chr', we paste the columns together along with sequence of rows using `sprintf` to update the 'samples' column.

```
library(splitstackshape)
setDT(expandRows(df, "samples"))[,
     samples := sprintf("%d-%d-%d-%s%d", chr, start, end, "s",1:.N) , chr][]
#  chr start end    samples
#1:   1    10  20 1-10-20-s1
#2:   1    10  20 1-10-20-s2
#3:   2     4  10  2-4-10-s1
#4:   2     4  10  2-4-10-s2
#5:   2     4  10  2-4-10-s3
```

NOTE: `data.table` will be loaded when we load `splitstackshape`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using base R (i.e. avoiding data.tables), with the following code:

```
df <- 'chr start end samples
        1   10   20    2
        2   4    10    3'

df <- read.table(text = df, header = TRUE)

duplicate_rows <- function(chr, starts, ends, samples) {
  expanded_samples <- paste0(chr, "-", starts, "-", ends, "-", "s", 1:samples)
  repeated_rows <- data.frame("chr" = chr, "starts" = starts, "ends" = ends, "samples" = expanded_samples)

  repeated_rows
}

expanded_rows <- Map(f = duplicate_rows, df$chr, df$start, df$end, df$samples)

new_df <- do.call(rbind, expanded_rows)
```

The basic idea is to define a function that will take a single row from your initial data.frame and duplicate rows based on the value in the `samples` column (as well as creating the distinct character strings you're after). This function is then applied to each row of your initial data.frame. The output is a list of data.frames that then need to be re-combined into a single data.frame using the `do.call` pattern.

The above code can be made cleaner by using the Hadley Wickham's [purrr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/purrr/index.html) package (on CRAN), and the data.frame specific version of map (see the documentation for the `by_row` function), but this may be overkill for what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Example using DataFrame function from S4Vector package:

```
df <- DataFrame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), y=1:5)
rep(df, df$y)
```

where y column represents the number of times to repeat its corresponding row.

Result:

```
DataFrame with 15 rows and 2 columns
              x         y
    <character> <integer>
1             a         1
2             b         2
3             b         2
4             c         3
5             c         3
...         ...       ...
11            e         5
12            e         5
13            e         5
14            e         5
15            e         5
```