# R geom_point() number of points reflect value in column

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

Say I have `mydf`, a dataframe which is as follows:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | 101 |
| Joe | 121 |
| Bill | 131 |

How would I go about creating a scatterplot in ggplot that takes the data in the `value` column (e.g., 101) and makes that number of points on a chart? Would this be a `stat =`  that I am unfamiliar with, or would I have to structure the data such that Mark, for example, has 101 unique rows, Joe has 121, etc.?

Comment: Not sure I get the problem, but read about `rep` and `geom_jitter`. What is the expected output, what is x and what is y?

Comment: Related (for the data preparation): [Repeat rows in a data frame AND add an increment field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690114/how-to-i-repeat-rows-in-a-data-frame-and-add-an-increment-field) and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** As suggest by Ben Bolker (many thanks) we could set the width of `geom_jitter` additionally we could add some colour asthetics:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  complete(Value = 1:Value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Name, y=Value, colour=Name))+
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1)
```

OR more compact as suggested by Henrik (many thanks) using `uncount`:

`ggplot(uncount(df, Value, .id = "y"), aes(x = Name, y = y)) + ...`

[image]

**First answer:**
Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr) # complete
df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  complete(Value = 1:Value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Name, y=Value))+
  geom_jitter()
```

[image]

Comment: maybe make your jitter width narrower ... ?

Comment: @Ben Bolker: Thank you very much. I will update my answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Comment: Given that you are happy to use `tidyr`, a bit more compact: `ggplot(uncount(d, Value, .id = "y"), aes(x = Name, y = y)) + ...`

Comment: @Henrik. Oh that' s great. Thank you very much. My first instinct was to use `uncount` but I got only `1` Now I know why I will add this to my answer!